# Transform title into dashed URL-friendly string

Tags: c#, replace

I would like to write a C# method that would transform any title into a URL friendly string, similar to what Stack Overflow does:

- replace spaces with dashes
- remove parenthesis
- etc.

I'm thinking of removing Reserved characters as per RFC 3986 standard (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)) but I don't know if that would be enough? It would make links workable, but does anyone know what other characters are being replaced here at stackoverflow? I don't want to end up with %-s in my URLs...

### Current implementation

```
string result = Regex.Replace(value.Trim(), @"[!*'""`();:@&+=$,/\\?%#\[\]<>«»{}_]");
return Regex.Replace(result.Trim(), @"[\s*[\-–—\s]\s*]", "-");
```

### My questions

1. Which characters should I remove?
2. Should I limit the maximum length of resulting string?
3. Anyone know which rules are applied on titles here on SO?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Rather than looking for things to replace, the list of [*unreserved* chars is so short](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3), it'll make for a nice clear regex.

```
return Regex.Replace(value, @"[^A-Za-z0-9_\.~]+", "-");
```

(Note that I didn't include the dash in the list of allowed chars; that's so it gets gobbled up by the "1 or more" operator [`+`] so that multiple dashes (in the original or generated or a combination) are collapsed, as per Dominic Rodger's excellent point.)

You may also want to remove common words ("the", "an", "a", etc.), although doing so can slightly change the meaning of a sentence. Probably want to remove any trailing dashes and periods as well.

Also strongly recommend you do what SO and others do, and include a unique identifier *other* than the title, and then only use that unique ID when processing the URL. So `http://example.com/articles/1234567/is-the-pop-catholic` (note the missing 'e') and `http://example.com/articles/1234567/is-the-pope-catholic` resolve to the same resource.

Comment: The whitelist approach, however, does prevent Unicode characters (in IRI) from going through.

Comment: @Bobince: Exactly. I have to provide our language related characters as well (from eastern european charset)

Comment: @Robert: IRI (RFC3987; http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt) changes the game. If it's important, you might want to mention it in your question. It doesn't look like it's hard to add the supported IRI values to the whitelist. For strong look-alikes, you may want to pre-filter them.

Comment: @TJCrowder: shouldn't . (dot) be escaped in your regular expression pattern?

Comment: @Robert: I don't *think* so, but frankly I'm not sure and would have to check. It's harmless to do so and I've edited the answer accordingly. The usual meaning of dot (any character here) doesn't make any sense within a character class construct. You have to escape `\`` (obviously), `-` (since it creates a range within the construct), and `]` (which closes it), but I don't *think* you have to escape most others.

Comment: @TJCrowder: You're right. Because it's contained inside an OR list of characters. Dot has no meaning inside of it. But it's probably still good practice to escape it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @TJCrowser: And just for the record. My dashed title in URL is just dummy data. It works without it just as you suggested it. So permalinks work against IDs and not against changeable data.

Comment: Allowing the . (dot) to remain caused a problem for me. For example, the title "My.HTML" would result in http://example.com/articles/123/My.HTML which my IIS intercepts (before it reaches the URL rewriter) and returns a 404.

Answer (score 2):

I would be doing:

```
string url = title;
url = Regex.Replace(url, @"^\W+|\W+$", "");
url = Regex.Replace(url, @"'\"", "");
url = Regex.Replace(url, @"_", "-");
url = Regex.Replace(url, @"\W+", "-");
```

Basically what this is doing is it:

- strips non-word characters from the beginning and end of the title;
- removes single and double quotes (mainly to get rid of apostrophes in the middle of words);
- replaces underscores with hyphens (underscores are technically a word character along with digits and letters); and
- replaces all groups of non-word characters with a single hyphen.

Comment: I'm wondering why this didn't get more votes? Very simple to understand and well explained. I also wonder whether String.Replace might be quicker for steps 2 and 3 which are litteral character replacements, but that's here nor there really.

I'm also interested in how the ^\W non-word character performs with unicode and non-latin languages? If it handles those even slightly well I'd say this is the best answer of the lot.

Final suggestion - I do like the earlier suggestion of replacing '&' with 'and'.

Comment: Oh - final thing, I think in the 3rd line (the second .Replace) the @"'\"" should actually be @"'"""

Answer (score 1):

Most "sluggifiers" (methods for converting to friendly-url type names) tend to do the following:

1. Strip everything except whitespace, dashes, underscores, and alphanumerics.
2. (Optional) Remove "common words" (the, a, an, of, et cetera).
3. Replace spaces and underscores with dashes.
4. (Optional) Convert to lowercase.

As far as I know, StackOverflow's sluggifier does #1, #3, and #4, but not #2.

Comment: So my replacements do the same ones: 1, 3 and 4. I just had to add underscore to the first reg ex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
string FriendlyURLTitle(string pTitle)
{
    pTitle = pTitle.Replace(" ", "-");
    pTitle = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pTitle);
    return Regex.Replace(pTitle, "\%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how I currently slug words.

```
        public static string Slug(this string value)
    {
        if (value.HasValue())
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            var slug = value.Trim().ToLowerInvariant();

            foreach (var c in slug)
            {
                switch (c)
                {
                    case ' ':
                        builder.Append("-");
                        break;
                    case '&':
                        builder.Append("and");
                        break;
                    default:

                        if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') && c != '-')
                        {
                            builder.Append(c);
                        }

                        break;
                }
            }

            return builder.ToString();
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I rather use regular expressions. Your many lines of code could easily be replaced by two regular expressions at most.

Comment: ya but at what cost will it be to you when that regular expression is very complicated and hard to understand. I would rather have maintainability then 2 cryptic regular expressions :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this one...

```
    public static string ToUrlFriendlyString(this string value)
    {
        value = (value ?? "").Trim().ToLower();

        var url = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char ch in value)
        {
            switch (ch)
            {
                case ' ':
                    url.Append('-');
                    break;
                default:
                    url.Append(Regex.Replace(ch.ToString(), @"[^A-Za-z0-9'()\*\\+_~\:\/\?\-\.,;=#\[\]@!$&]", ""));
                    break;
            }
        }

        return url.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
string output = Uri.UnescapeDataString(input);
```